# How to add a new element in the first open slot in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, object

So I want to fill an array up with objects, and whenever I create a new object I want it to go into the first empty spot in the array. For example, the first object created should automatically go into the first spot in the array, the second create object should automatically go into the second slot in the array, etc...

Comment: Java arrays are not dynamic data structures (they do not grow and shrink; but there is a `Collection` called `ArrayList` that is backed by an array). In short, you'd need to track the current index of the array and it would start at 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using an array, you must keep a separate index variable that keeps track of the next unoccupied index of the array.

```
Object[] arr = new Object[10];
int index = 0;

public void add(Object obj)
{
    if (index < arr.length)
        arr[index++] = obj; // add an object to the first empty spot, if the array is not full
}
```